# Two Connections types in one method (SQL and OLEDB)

Tags: vb.net, oledb, sqlclient, oledbcommand, oledbdatareader

I have two connections types to be used in my app. One is SQL Server, using the `SqlClient.Connection` type. The other one uses the `OleDb.Connection` type.

The question is, when using a `DataAdapter`, `DataReader`, and `Command`, how can I use one reference for each with both connections?

As an example, I want to use a reader like this:

```
Dim MyReader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
```

to check my data with an `OleDbConnection`, and then use *same reader* to check data from the second `SqlClient` connection. That is, I want to do something like this (pseudocode):

```
Dim con 
Dim MyReader
con = oledb.connection
MyReader = mymethod(con)
con = sql.sqlclient.conection
MyReader = mymethod2(con)
```

How can I do this in real code?

I need help in how to declare data components for two different connection types inside the same method or function.

Comment: You can't. They are different types. That's the point. One object can't be two different types. If you want to use one object then it would have to be `OleDb` and then use the OLE DB provider for SQL Server instead of `SqlClient`. Don't do that though. Just use two different objects for the two different databases. You're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: Note that ADO.NET providers all inherit the same base classes, so if you want to write code that will work for all providers then you can have it use those base types. E.g. `OlebConnection` and `SqlConnection` both inherit `DbConnection`, so you can use a variable of type `DbConnection` and assign objects of the two derived types to it. The objects still have to be those derived types though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare multiple variables. It's really not a big deal to do so.

But, if you really want to do this (again: not the best idea) one thing you can keep in mind is these objects all inherit from a common set of types in the `System.Data.Common` namespace. So it possible to write code like this:

```
Dim con As System.Data.Common.DbConnection = New OleDbConnection("connection string here")
Dim cmd As System.Data.Common.DbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * ... ", con)

con.Open()
Dim rdr As System.Data.Common.DbDataReader = con.ExecuteReader()
While rdr.Read()
    ' ...
End While
con.Close()

con = New SqlClient.SqlConnection("connection string here")
cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT * ...", con)
con.Open()
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
While rdr.Read()
    ' ...
End While
```

But again: you really are better off using separate variables.

Comment: Thank you Coehoorn, it is very clear. However, I will try to use your code suggestion just for practice.